# How To Validate If A Conversation Object With Particular Partcipants (Many to Many Field) Exist or nott in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
class Conversation(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="conversation")
```

Urls.py

```
path('api/conversations/', views.ConversationListView.as_view(),
         name='conversation-list'),
```

Serializers.py

```
class ConversationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    participants = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                                      many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Conversation
        fields = ['id', 'participants']
```

Views.py

```
class ConversationListView(APIView):   
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        conversations = Conversation.objects.all()
        serializer = ConversationSerializer(
            conversations, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ConversationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So I would like to make a POST request on "api/conversations/" with this object:

```
{"participants": [2,3]} or {"participants": [3,2]}
```

**BUT I would like to check first whether a conversation with participants are both User(id=2) and User(id=3) exist or not. If exists, I need to raise an error. If not exist, create a new conversation. So there is only one conversation between User(id=2) and User(id=3).**

What I know so far is I have to make **validate_participants(self, value)** in the serializer. But I still can't figure out what is the logic to check it. I've tried using **Conversation.objects.filter(participants__in=[2,3])** but I think it doesn't work because it does not return the conversation object that has both User(id=2) and User(id=3) as participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves my problem. Add this to ConversationSerializer

```
def validate_participants(self, value):
    query1 = Conversation.objects.filter(participants=value[0])
    query2 = Conversation.objects.filter(participants=value[1])

    if query1.intersection(query2).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            "Conversation with these participants has exist")
    return value
```